# Problem of " The kernel is not responsing to dynamic evaluation "

Tags: parallelization, mathematica-online

I am having this error again and again while using parallel computation. The code is fine because
it runs when I am not using parallel computation. But as it takes a lot of time to run ( around 3 - 4 days ) I have decided to go with parallel computation but as I am going to use it after 1 or 1.5 days it shows me this error [image]

Can anyone tell me how I can use parallel computing without having this problem?

I could not find the place to upload the code. If it is needed I can give a link !

Comment: Does it help if you call `ParallelTable` with the option `ProgressReporting -> False`?

Comment: I have not checked with this ... I will try and get back to you.

Comment: @JasonB. Now I am getting different error. 
 DynamicOptionValue::nodef: Unknown option ProgressReporting for ParallelTable.

Comment: @JasonB. Now I am getting a different error. 
 

weights6 = 
  ParallelTable[
   Sum[a6[[Position[b6, level6[[i]]][[j, 1]]]], {j, 1, 
     Length[Position[b6, level6[[i]]]]}], {i, 1, Length[level6]}, 
   ProgressReporting -> False];

DynamicCloudConnect::verr: This version of Mathematica is no longer supported for use with the Wolfram Cloud beginning Wed 1 Dec 2021. Please upgrade your license or contact us.

DynamicOptionValue::nodef: Unknown option ProgressReporting for ParallelTable.

DynamicOptionValue::nodef: Unknown option ProgressReporting for ParallelTable.